# Avoid submit form twice Parsley - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

I'm trying to avoid submit form twice.
Basically, I would like to disable the submit button after the first click and if the form is validated.

I'm using **Parsley**, and this is what I tried to do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.Parsley.on('parsley:form:validated', function(e){
        if (e.validationResult) {
            alert("OK");
            $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }else{
            alert("KO");
        }
    });
</script>
```

But it seems like it never called. The alert never appears.

What am I doing wrong?

Please, note that I added that script inside the layout that every page with a form extend. So because of that I didn't use the id directly.

Comment: refer, http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/simple.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved in this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('form').parsley().on('form:validated', function(e) {
            if (e.validationResult) {
                $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```